# Selecting first visible element with classname

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to select the first element with a specific class that is also visible. I only want to select the one element and store it as a variable.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('className'); // Get all visible elements with classname.
var element= elements[0]; // Return only the first element from this NodeList
```

For my specific use case, I'm attempting to then retrieve its background image, so this is what I've got so far. My variable returns "undefined".

```
var bg = element.css('background-image'); // Returns url('http://www.google.com/imageurl')
```

I'm using jQuery, but plain JavaScript is welcome, too. Whatever gets the job done the best.

Comment: `var element` is a plain JS element. `.css` is a method of a *jQuery* element. You're attempting to use jQuery methods on non-jQuery objects.

Comment: @Tyler Roper Thanks for pointing that out! I didn't realize that was an issue until now. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I would do using JQuery:

```
var element = $(".classname:visible:first");
var bg = element.css('background-image');
```

`element` contains the first element of the specified classname that is visible.

Comment: I'm receiving the error _"Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '.element:visible' is not a valid selector."_ I believe the error rests with the `:visible` selector, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. :/

Comment: @Chopin23 Sorry I keep making mistakes. Edited my answer. It should work now but I could not test.

Comment: Not a problem. :) I edited my code to match yours and I'm no longer getting an error, so I'm one step closer! However, `var element = $(".classname:visible");` returns `a.fn.init [selector: ".classname:visible", prevObject: n.fn.init(1), context: document]`, while `var element = $(".classname:visible").first();` returns `a.fn.init [selector: "", prevObject: a.fn.init(0), context: document]` . Once this returns the correct element, I'm sure the background code will work.

Comment: @Chopin23 when you say it returns what you show. Is it what the variable 'bg' equals ?

Comment: I believe your previous version of code is what worked for me. My code is as follows `var element = $(".classname:visible:first");`. The second line of code to retrieve the background image url is working as expected now. :) My elements were also loading after the DOM was technically loaded, so I also needed to wrap my function in `$(window).on("load", function()` for my specific use case. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Chopin23 Cool. Edited my code again to match what worked.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `:visible` selector. Something like this `$('.classname:visible')` .

https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Answer (score 0):

`$('selector:visible')` will get you visible elements matching the given selector

`.eq(n)` will return the nth node from those matched

`.css('backgroundImage')` will give you the background image

`.match(/"(.+)"/)[1]` will then return just the URL of the background image:

```js
var specialElement = $('.example:visible').eq(1);
specialElement.append(specialElement.css('backgroundImage').match(/"(.+)"/)[1]);
```

```css
body {
  color: white;
}
.example {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.special {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
  </header>
  <main>
    <section>
      <article class="example" style="background-image:url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/374815/pexels-photo-374815.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500');">
        <h2>Bananas</h2>
        <p>Bananas are a great source of potassium.</p>
      </article>
      <article class="example special" style="background-image:url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/707194/pexels-photo-707194.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500');">
        <h2>Apples</h2>
        <p>An apple a day will keep the doctor away!</p>
      </article>
      <article class="example" style="background-image:url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/1667580/pexels-photo-1667580.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500');">
        <h2>Oranges</h2>
        <p>Oranges make great juice.</p>
      </article>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>
```